# How can I check if I have mysqli in my web server using cPanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, cpanel, mediatemple

I'm using...

- PHP version 5.4.28
- Filezilla
- Wordpress
- cPanel
- MediaTemple hosting

I get this error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()**,
after trying to connect to my database with mysqli functions. I've read online that either mysqli isn't enabled, it may not be installed. I know I have to check my php.ini file located in /usr/local/lib/, but I don't how know look for that. I'm using cPanel's WHM and it looks like this... [cpanel WHM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHdl9.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't check the php.ini file, but your answers actually helped. The answer is... NO I don't have mysqli installed on my web server. Now I just need to figure out how to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have WHM you can see and install PHP modules via Easy Apache.

1) Search "Easy Apache" in search box of WHM

2) Click "show more" from DEFAULT profile.

3) You can see all installed modules. Check for MySQL Improved. It's mysqli.

[image]

Comment: On WHM no there're a tools for see modules on PHP working, only show latest compilation, but it's possible that not correct information. Best way it's a Cpanel user interface. If ypu need correct information must ask, to php not WHM/Cpanel latest compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create phpinfo page in your account through cPanel file manger and then try to browse that to check all php information of your server.

Here are the php code of phpinfo page.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
php?>
```

Comment: On shell ssh

    php -m |grep mysql